# Datastore composite index for querying embedded entity

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have the following entity:

[image: I have the following entity]

**This is an example query:**

```
$list = 'My List';
$query->filter('isUnsubscribed.'.$list, '=', '0');  
$query->filter('methodAdded.'.$list, '=', 'Import'); 
$query->filter('dateAdded.'.$list, '<', '13.01.2018');
```

**And here is the problem:**

Everything is working fine if my index is:

```
- kind: Contacts
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: isUnsubscribed.My List
  - name: methodAdded.My List
  - name: dateAdded.My List
```

But I cannot create index for every list, because the users can create their own lists. So I tried with this index, but it is not working:

```
- kind: Contacts
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: isUnsubscribed
  - name: methodAdded
  - name: dateAdded
```

Is there a way to create the index without specifying the properties in the embedded entity, maybe a wildcard or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to query user data stored in property names (this includes embedded property names too). Always structure your data so that variable data ends up as values, there as well known (by the programmer) data is the kind/property names.

In your example, have `isUnsubscribed` as a repeated property (array) of lists users have unsubscribed from - all the ones you currently have as 0 values. You can have a second list `isSubscribed` for everything that has 1.

Comment: The lists are stored as an array in the property **inList**, I know them, I don't want to query the property names, I already have them and I make a query for each list, my data is in the values. The problem is that I want to use inequality filters by **dateAdded** and I need an index, but I cannot create an index for each list **("dateAdded.My List", "dateAdded.Test", "dateAdded.Test 1")** because one user can have 3 lists but the other can have 300. Is there a way to create the index using only the main property **dateAdded**?